# Fetching values from mysql table and convert to json object

Tags: php, json

I am currently fetching values from mysql database through a  foreach loop. Then I am placing the values inside an array and converting the end results into a json object. But I am having difficulties getting the values in the proper json format in order to use with a third party api. How could I get those values in the format shown below?

Desired Format:

```
[{education_level: "education_level", elementary: 3, middle_school: 4}]
```

Current Format:

```
{"education":"education","0":{"elementary":3},"1":{"middle_school":4}}
```

Generate json object

```
header("Content-type: application/json");
//get the course list
$education_query = $db_con->prepare("SELECT a.type, COUNT(1) AS cnt
FROM academy a
GROUP BY a.type");
$education_query->execute();
$data = $education_query->fetchAll();
$output = array('education'=>'education');
foreach ($data as $row) {
    array_push($output, array($row["type"]=>intval($row["cnt"])));
}// foreach ($data as $row) {
echo json_encode($output);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried putting the output in another empty array that is not a key value pair.

`echo json_encode(array($output));`